# Replace all characters except for the last occurrence

Tags: go

I am performing a replace of characters on a string like this:

```
result = strings.ReplaceAll(result, ".", "_")
```

This works as expected, but I want to preserve the last occurence of the `.` and not replace it, just leave it alone.

Is there a fancy way doing this?

Answer (score 3):

The most obvious way to handle this would be to combine `Replace` and `Count`:

```
func ReplaceAllExceptLast(d string, o string, n string) string {
    strings.Replace(d, o, n, strings.Count(d, o) - 1)
}
```

I don't think this would be the most optimal solution, however. For me, the best option would be to do this:

```
func ReplaceAllExceptLast(d string, o string, n string) string {
    ln := strings.LastIndex(d, o)
    if ln == -1 {
        return d
    }

    return strings.ReplaceAll(d[:ln], o, n) + d[ln:]
}
```

This works by getting the index of the last occurrence of the value you want to replace, and then doing a replace-all on the string up to that point. For example:

```
println(ReplaceAllExceptLast("a", ".", "_"))
println(ReplaceAllExceptLast("a.b", ".", "_"))
println(ReplaceAllExceptLast("a.b.c", ".", "_"))
println(ReplaceAllExceptLast("a.b.c.d", ".", "_"))
```

will produce:

```
a
a.b
a_b.c
a_b_c.d
```

Answer (score 2):

Split into `[]string`, then `Join` all but last ;)

```
func ReplaceAllButLast(data, old, new string) string {
    split := strings.Split(data, old)
    if len(split) < 3 {
        return data
    }
    last := len(split) - 1
    return strings.Join(split[:last], new) + old + split[last]
}
```

https://go.dev/play/p/j8JJP-p_Abk

```
func main() {
    println(ReplaceAllButLast("a", ".", "_"))
    println(ReplaceAllButLast("a.b", ".", "_"))
    println(ReplaceAllButLast("a.b.c", ".", "_"))
    println(ReplaceAllButLast("a.b.c.d", ".", "_"))
}
```

produced

```
a
a.b
a_b.c
a_b_c.d
```

UPDATE

That was a joke, just to be *fancy*

Best way is to count the number of matches and replace `Count()-1`, the second it to `ReplaceAll` until last match position and using `Join` to be the slowest

```
func ReplaceAllButLast_Count(data, old, new string) string {
    cnt := strings.Count(data, old)
    if cnt < 2 {
        return data
    }
    return strings.Replace(data, old, new, cnt-1)
}

func ReplaceAllButLast_Replace(data, old, new string) string {
    idx := strings.LastIndex(data, old)
    if idx <= 0 {
        return data
    }

    return strings.ReplaceAll(data[:idx], old, new) + data[idx:]
}

func ReplaceAllButLast_Join(data, old, new string) string {
    split := strings.Split(data, old)
    if len(split) < 3 {
        return data
    }
    last := len(split) - 1
    return strings.Join(split[:last], new) + old + split[last]
}
```

Benchmark using `a.b.c.d -> a_b_c.d`

```
goos: windows
goarch: amd64
pkg: example.org
cpu: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-8550U CPU @ 1.80GHz
Benchmark_Count-8       16375098            70.05 ns/op        8 B/op          1 allocs/op
Benchmark_Replace-8     11213830           108.5 ns/op        16 B/op          2 allocs/op
Benchmark_Slice-8        5460445           217.6 ns/op        80 B/op          3 allocs/op
```

Answer (score 1):

The first solution comes to my mind is `Positive Lookahead` of regular expression

`[.](?=.*[.])`

However, the `(?=re)` is not supported in Golang [re2](https://github.com/google/re2/wiki/Syntax)

---

We can use `Non-capturing group` to implement it in this way

- First use
  `(?:[.])`( Match a single character present in the list below [.]) to find all dot indexes.
- Then replace dot with '_' except the last one.

Sample

```golang
func replaceStringByIndex(str string, replacement string, index int) string {
    return str[:index] + replacement + str[index+1:]
}

func replaceDotIgnoreLast(str string, replacement string) string {
    pattern, err := regexp.Compile("(?:[.])")
    if err != nil {
        return ""
    }

    submatches := pattern.FindAllStringSubmatchIndex(str, -1)
    for _, submatch := range submatches[:len(submatches)-1] {
        str = replaceStringByIndex(str, replacement, submatch[0])
    }

    return str
}

func main() {
    str := "1.2"
    fmt.Println(replaceDotIgnoreLast(str, "_"))
    str = "1.2.3"
    fmt.Println(replaceDotIgnoreLast(str, "_"))
    str = "1.2.3.4"
    fmt.Println(replaceDotIgnoreLast(str, "_"))
}
```

Result

```
1.2
1_2.3
1_2_3.4
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Use **strings.Count** to count the occurrence of the string you want to replace
2. Pass count-1 to **strings.Replace** to omit the last occurrence

```golang
func ReplaceAllButLast(input string, find string, replace string) string {
    occurrencesCount := strings.Count(input, find)
    return strings.Replace(input, find, replace, occurrencesCount-1)
}
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes